# Loadbitmap is compiling and working well as x86, but not working when compiling as x64

Tags: winapi, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I am new to C++. This is adapted code by me from a WIN32 API book.
It is working as desired only when x86 mode in debug is on. When there is x64, it is compiling but not working.
I tried to change GWL_HINSTANCE to GWLP_HINSTANCE with no result.

```
hBmpBkgr = LoadBitmapW((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_STONE));
hBkBrush = CreatePatternBrush(hBmpBkgr);
SetClassLongW(hWnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)hBkBrush);

hBmpBall = LoadBitmapW((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_BALL));
GetObjectW(hBmpBall, sizeof(bm), (LPSTR)&bm);

hMemDcFrame = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
hBmpFrame = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rect.right, rect.bottom);
SelectObject(hMemDcFrame, hBmpFrame);

SetGraphicsMode(hMemDcFrame, GM_ADVANCED);
```

Comment: Have found most probably.     I need to change this:  GetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE) to this GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE). Any comments appreciated

Comment: Reason is in official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw answer yourself if you're happy.

Answer (score 1):

[SetClassLongW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongw):

> Replaces the specified 32-bit (long) value at the
>   specified offset into the extra class memory or the WNDCLASSEX
>   structure for the class to which the specified window belongs.

**Note: This function has been superseded by the SetClassLongPtr function. To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use [SetClassLongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptrw).**

In addition, [`LoadBitmap` is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) and [DrawFrameControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawframecontrol).]

For more details, please refer: [LoadBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadbitmapw)

Comment: Hi, @Kidd, is this answer helpful to you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it does solve the issue.